# xcode 4.3.2 archive build not creating dsym

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

I have an old project developed with Xcode 4, i remember doing xarchive on Xcode which generated dsym properly. but on the latest version that is x 4.3.2 the xarchive created doesn't have the dsym file. i verified the setting these setting

1. dwarf with dsym for both debug and release

what else is causing issue, is there any other setting which i should take care ? please advice a way to fix this issue.

note: i selecting archive-debug and not archive release in the scheme. thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Verify that the `Generate Debug Symbols` are set to `YES` in `Build Settings`. Make sure you clean your target before compiling. After doing so, make sure you're looking for the `.dSYM` in the right location.

- Right Click Archive from Organizer and `Show In Finder`
- Right click `.xarchive` File and `Show Package Contents`
- Navigate to `dSYMs` directory.

Comment: it is set to yes, no change :(. dsym folder is present inside xarchive and it is empty

Answer (score 4):

**Identifying the problem**

1. Check your build settings for both release and debug configuration:

   - Generate Debug Symbols → Yes
   - Debug Information... → DWARF with DSYM
   - Deployment Postprocessing → YES
   - Strip Linked Product... → No
   - Strip Debug... → No
2. Try check the Report Navigator. 
   In my case, the dSYM file has not been generated, and there hasn't been a corresponding line that goes like `"Generate Appname.dSYM ...in {path}"`
   But there's been Fabric installed, and it logged the fact of the dSYM file's absence:

[image: no dsym]

Just filer the Report Navigator by "dSYM".

**Fixing**

In my case I've just had to do what I'm asked of:

> DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for ALL
>   configurations.

Also, it may turn out that dSYM file is being generated in an unexpected place. Check environment variables, especially `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` and `DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME`.

To embed the dSYM within the app bundle, just set `DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH` to `$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH)` and `DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME` to `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME).dSYM`

**Checking**

Now the build should create dSYM for your target

[image: generate target.dSYM]